# google maps to trace the location and calculate distance using python django

Tags: python, django

i want to include google map in my project to calculate the distance between the current location and destination. My project is python django based project to provide the distance mapping .

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distance between two positions using below method.

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def distance_between_zipcodes(lat1, lat2, lng1, lng2):
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lng1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lng2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = (sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    distance = R * c

    # km to miles
    distance /= 1.609344

    return distance
```

**lat1** = latitude of current position

**lon1** = longitude of current position

**lat2** = latitude of destination position

**lon3** = longitude of destination position

**R** = Radius of Earth

Install geopy:

```
pip install geopy
```

To calculate latitude and longitude:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

def get_lat_lng(zip_code):
    geocoder = GoogleV3()
    location = geocoder.geocode(query=str(zip_code))

    if location:
        address, lat, lng = location.address, location.latitude, location.longitude

    return address, lat, lng
```

Comment: I suggest looking up geodjango